Sequelize Hooks is not triggering
I am facing an issue where the beforeCreate hook in my Sequelize model is not being triggered when I attempt to create a new record. I have defined hooks in my model, but it seems they are not executing as expected. Below is the detailed description of the problem and my setup.
/* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../config/database');
const { User } = require('./User');
const { Company } = require('./Company');

const hooks = {
  beforeCreate: async (project) => {
    console.log('Before Create Hook Triggered');
    console.log('Project before setting ID:', project);
    if (!project.project_id) {
      let uniqueIdentifier;
      let isUnique = false;

      while (!isUnique) {
        uniqueIdentifier = `P${Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
          .toString()
          .padStart(6, '0')}`;

        const existingProject = await Project.findOne({
          where: { project_id: uniqueIdentifier },
        });

        if (!existingProject) {
          isUnique = true;
        }
      }
      console.log('Generated Project ID:', uniqueIdentifier); // Debug log
      project.project_id = uniqueIdentifier;
      console.log('Project after setting ID:', project); // Debug log
    } else {
      console.log('Project ID already set:', project.project_id); // Debug log
    }
  },
  beforeValidate: (project) => {
    console.log('Before Validate Hook Triggered');
    if (!project.company_id) {
      if (!project.procurement_manager_id) {
        throw new Error('Internal Project: Procurement manager needed');
      }
      if (!project.project_manager_id) {
        throw new Error('Internal Project: Project manager needed');
      }
      if (!project.finance_manager_id) {
        throw new Error('Internal Project: Finance manager needed');
      }
    } else {
      if (project.procurement_manager_id) {
        throw new Error(
          'External Project: Procurement manager should not be set',
        );
      }
      if (project.project_manager_id) {
        throw new Error('External Project: Project manager should not be set');
      }
      if (project.finance_manager_id) {
        throw new Error('External Project: Finance manager should not be set');
      }
      if (!project.company_user_id) {
        throw new Error('External Project: Company user needed');
      }
    }
  },
};
const Project = sequelize.define(
  'project',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        isUnique(value, next) {
          Project.findOne({
            where: {
              name: value,
              id: { [Sequelize.Op.ne]: this.id },
            },
          })
            .then((project) => {
              if (project) {
                return next('Sorry, This Project Already Exists');
              }
              return next();
            })
            .catch((err) => next(err));
        },
      },
    },
    contract_number: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    status: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    procurement_manager_id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      references: { model: User, key: 'id' },
    },
    project_manager_id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      references: { model: User, key: 'id' },
    },
    finance_manager_id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      references: { model: User, key: 'id' },
    },
    company_user_id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      references: { model: User, key: 'id' },
    },
    payment_status: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: 'unpaid',
    },
    project_id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        isUnique(value, next) {
          Project.findOne({
            where: {
              project_id: value,
              id: { [Sequelize.Op.ne]: this.id },
            },
          })
            .then((project) => {
              if (project) {
                return next('Sorry, This Project ID Already Exists');
              }
              return next();
            })
            .catch((err) => next(err));
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    hooks,
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  },
);

// Define associations
Project.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'projectManager',
  foreignKey: 'project_manager_id',
});
Project.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'procurementManager',
  foreignKey: 'procurement_manager_id',
});
Project.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'financeManager',
  foreignKey: 'finance_manager_id',
});
Project.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'companyUser',
  foreignKey: 'company_user_id',
});
Project.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Project.belongsTo(Company, { foreignKey: 'company_id' });
User.hasMany(Project, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Company.hasMany(Project, { foreignKey: 'company_id' });

module.exports = { Project };

Expected Behavior
The beforeCreate and beforeValidate hooks should trigger as expected, logging the relevant debug information to the console.
**Actual Behaviour **
The beforeValidate is only trigerring
